# What is "vulgar white of personal aims"? Why is it "white"?

Tags: meaning, wording-choice, elizabeth-barrett-browning, aurora-leigh

From *[Aurora Leigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurora_Leigh)* by Elizabeth Barrett Browning:

> 'I have not stood long on the strand of life,
>   And these salt waters have had scarcely time
>   To creep so high up as to wet my feet.
>   I cannot judge these tides–I shall, perhaps.
>   A woman's always younger than a man
>   At equal years, because she is disallowed
>   Maturing by the outdoor sun and air,
>   And kept in long-clothes past the age to walk.
>   Ah well, I know you men judge otherwise!
>   You think a woman ripens as a peach,–
>   In the cheeks, chiefly. Pass it to me now;
>   I'm young in age, and younger still, I think,
>   As a woman. But a child may say amen
>   To a bishop's prayer and see the way it goes;
>   And I, incapable to loose the knot
>   Of social questions, can approve, applaud
>   August compassion, christian thoughts that shoot
>   Beyond the **vulgar white** of personal aims.
>   Accept my reverence.'

Why is it "vulgar white"? Does it refer to white paper, or white clothes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Metaphor, mainly**

I wasn’t able to find any exposition of the meaning of this particular passage. However, I think the meaning is fairly straightforward. Here “white” doesn’t refer to the color of “long-clothes” or anything concrete previously mentioned in the poem.

Rather, I believe “white” here is being used as a metaphor for **purity**. It’s not precisely the white of clothing—thought I suspect the origin of the metaphor owes something to the idea of a white robe as not having gotten dirty yet (see, e.g. the symbolism of white clothing in Revelation in the Christian Bible). The contrast here is between self-interest, which pretends to be “christian,” and is far more common (i.e. vulgar), and true “christian” values, which are more rarefied. The “thoughts” here referenced are Romney’s: he works as a social activist, which Aurora genuinely admires.

**So: personal aims are “white” because they have the *appearance* of purity, and are “vulgar” because apparent charity born out of self-interest is far more common than genuine kindness.**